# How to remove shadow for specific element in CUBA Platform?

Tags: css, cuba-platform

I added a shadow to some of my buttons. With the :not selector i deselected some elements like link button and pickerfield button. My problem now is that there is also a shadow in my logout section. It didnt work with c-logout and c-login-button. Someone here who has an idea?

```
.v-button:not(.v-button-link):not(.v-button-c-pickerfield-button):not(.v-button-c-logout-button):not(.v-button-c-login-button)  {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px darkgray;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, added some missing stylenames in ext-main-screen.xml and this is my scss:

```
  .v-button
        :not(.v-button-link)
        :not(.v-button-c-pickerfield-button)
        :not(.v-button-c-sidemenu-collapse-button)
        :not(.v-button-c-settings-button)
        :not(.v-button-c-logout-button)
        :not(.v-button-c-login-button)  {
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px darkgray;
    }
```